# Can the JVM optimize multiple reads from an array

Tags: java, jvm, java-memory-model

Can the JVM optimize array reads when reading the same index multiple times? Consider the following:

```
public static void foo(int[] array) {
   for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
       int value1 = array[i];
       ...
       int value2 = array[i];
       ...
    }
    ...
}
```

`array[i]` is read twice in the loop. Assuming `array[i]` is not reassigned in the loop, is the JVM allowed to assume that `array[i]` did not change and thus read its value just once? Since `array` is a passed-in mutable object, it could conceivably have changed between the first and second read.

I've looked the at the generated byte code and it does indeed read `array[i]` twice (`daload`). Is the JVM allowed to optimize this into one read?

Comment: Can we assume you're asking about a HotSpot VM?

Comment: It's really a question about the Java memory model. The JVM vendor is irrelevant. In reality it will be Sun's Hotspot JVM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the optimizer only considers single thread data flow, it doesn't care if a variable is changed by another thread, unless volatile/synchronized are involved.

Even if there's no optimization, the 2nd read should be really fast, around 1ns, since the data is most likely in L1 cache.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think the JVM will optimize this read, but the overhead of the `daload` operation should be insignificant.

If you want to read the value from the array only once, try assigning to a local variable (costing some trivial local variable stack memory)

```
int origVal = array[i];
int value1 = origVal;
...
int value2 = origVal;
```

Tests should prove that the change is arbitrary.